# NSAutoReleasePool Leaks on allocWithZone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-leaks

So this has been confusing me for a while. I am running my app in the "Profile" Mode trying to find memory leaks in my app. I think I got all of them expect when I click on the Map part of my application it reports back that a reference to `NSAutoreleasePool` was leaked from the Foundation Library. I check the trace of the object but it only reports back from the method `allocWithZone`. It seems to leak only once on matter how many times I `alloc` and `dealloc` that view controller. I did a search of my code and the only reference I make to `NSAutoreleasePool` is in the main.m file. Is this an Apple bug (which I doubt) or am I doing something wrong?

**main.m**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: if you try and archive (make sure you set it to build for iOS device) it will point out where in your code memory leaks are occurring. It is a work around but it has helped me find lots of mystery errors that I couldn't figure out with stack traces.

Comment: Check in your Map part class file, you are trying to release any object in that class file which may be reference to other class file or vice-versa. Check it by commenting line by line in your dealloc or viewDidUnlaod or wherever you are releasing the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was an Apple bug. The same amount of memory is leaked in the other question which leads me to believe they are the same bug. I did an extensive code audit and nothing seemed to be working to get rid of the leak. Oh well I hope they fix it soon. [NSAutoReleasePool Leaks on allocWithZone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903509/nsautoreleasepool-leaks-on-allocwithzone)